I'm looking for an anime film I saw on TV in Austria about 5 years ago
I've been looking for this film for such a long time I'm considering it might have been a fever dream, but maybe one of you know what I'm looking for :)
The protagonist was a teenage boy with black hair who had a normal life, but suddenly was sucked into some fantasy world?
He received a sword and was told if he found this one rare jewel, he could wish for one thing and it would come true.
He befriends a talking alligator who could walk on his hind-legs or something, and there's a subplot with a princess with really long white hair and an evil guy who wants to take over the world when he finds the jewel.
There's also a cat girl who falls in love with the protagonist I think. 
There was an epic showdown at the end where the protagonist gets the jewel from the cat girl and instead of wishing to go back to his world he wishes for all the damage in the fantasy world to be undone, because the world was falling apart or something.
And then he wakes up because it was all a dream.
The movie might have been made in the late 90s or early 2000s, but I honestly am not good at recognizing those things.
Does anyone recall the name of the movie? :)

Maybe the anime movie you are looking for is 
Brave Story(2006)

When eleven-year-old Wataru is told he can change his destiny by entering a magic gateway into another world, he jumps at the chance. But on his quest to find the Tower of Fortune and be granted any wish, he must conjure up all his bravery to battle a world of demons, his own friends and ultimately himself. 

It matches the plot you described, and a trailer for the movie has a character that looks like a talking alligator.

Yes it definitely is!! Thank you so much! :D

It would be nice if you confirm my answer as a correct one :)
